# How to place a block in a random area within a radius

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a disco minigame, and when I /fill make the floor drop out, there needs to be platforms in random places for the player to jump on, and be saved. How do I do this?  (if there is a way to do this with command blocks, then that is recomended. I kinda need to do it with command blocks)

Comment: Will the platforms be at the same height as the floor that drops out, or below it?

Comment: I would like them to be at the same height, but if they are below, I can totally work with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, summon an ArmorStand:

```
/summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {Marker:1,Invisible:1,NoGravity:1,Invulnerable:1,CustomName:"Platformer"}
```

While the floor is still in place, to generate a platform, use `/spreadplayers` to put the ArmorStand in a random location:

```
/spreadplayers X Z 0 D false @e[name=Platformer,type=ArmorStand]
```

Replace `X` and `Z` with the coordinates of the center of your arena, and `D` with the distance from center to edge of the arena:

[image: Diagram showing the values of X, Z and D]

After spreading the `ArmorStand`, have it replace the floor below it with another block type (you can use something like monster egg stone if you want the platforms to look the same as the original floor):

```
/execute @e[type=ArmorStand,name=Platformer] ~ ~ ~ /fill ~1 ~-1 ~1 ~-1 ~-1 ~-1 cobblestone 0 replace stone
```

You should then be able to replace the original floor block with air (in this example I'm using stone) to have only the platforms still existing:

```
/fill X1 Y1 Z1 X2 Y2 Z2 air 0 replace stone
```

Comment: That's a really creative use of `/spreadplayers`! Upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You could teleport invisible armor stands and do `/fill X Y Z X2 Y2 Z2 -block of floor-`

```
/execute @e[type=ArmorStand] ~ ~ ~ /fill ~-1 ~ ~-1 ~1 ~ ~1 -block of platform-

/fill X Y Z X2 Y2 Z2 air 0 replace -block of floor- 0
```

Comment: While this explains how to make platforms, the bigger question is how to randomly distribute them.

Answer (score -1):

I would summon armor stands in every block with `[nogravity:1,invisible:1,invulnerable:1,CustomName:"Anything"]` and then do `execute @e ~ ~ ~ [type=armorstand,Name=anything] setblock ~ ~ ~ stone`
Instead of stone usw ans block you want